# Custom Scroll-Picker Functionality in React-Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I want to create a custom Picker component, with the same functionality as the [iOS Picker](https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/ios/controls/pickers/). The problem is that I want a completely different UI, basically a horizontal scrollview with two methods of input:

First one is easy, clicking one item results in that item being selected. The second way of inputting should be by scrolling, where the center one gets selected (like the iOS Picker). That's where I'm stuck.

While planing, I thought about using [react-native-snap-carousel](https://github.com/archriss/react-native-snap-carousel), my problem with that is that it needs a fixed itemWidth, which isn't suitable for text as the elements.

I also thought about somehow enabling snapping for my List, but that seems only to be possible with `pagingEnabled = true`, which isn't suitable for my use case.

What else could I try?

Thank's to anyone who is willing to help!

Comment: @ Konstantin Krauthäuser   Have u found a solution for this issue? i have been trying to achieve the same. all i could find was this library which is not maintained and has a lot of bugs when scrolling `https://github.com/rdhox/react-native-smooth-picker`